# Kentia Palm Yellow Stems

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, indoors, plant-care

My Kentia Palm bought 6 weeks ago has started developing some yellow stems with leaves darkening and somewhat drying and contracting (see images below). It started on a small bunch of stems a few weeks ago and I thought that I had solve the issue by cutting that part but larger stems/leaves are now impacted and it seems to be worsening.
I water once a week usually until it drips a little bit through (maybe between one cup and one pint of water max). The plant is below a velux SE facing and 4m from a south facing window. The house temperature is usually set at 22C (we like it cosy). Humidity in the house is around 35%.

I want to understand whether I need to water less or more. I can't get a clear answer from my quick Google search.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]
[image: Picture 4]

Comment: chances are good the light is too low and you are watering too much.  Ease off on the water, when they are new plants the smaller fronds do not have a well developed root system